# JavaScript delete object

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm doing some ajax request and loading some new content.
In my homepage I'm using :

```
var App = function($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
    if ($.isFunction(this.init)) this.init();
}

App.prototype = {
    init: function() {          
        console.log(this);
    }
}

$(function() {
    var $homepage = $('#app #projects');
    $homepage = new App($homepage);
});
```

I'm trying to reset my object when I load a new content and then create a new one when I come back to my homepage. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any ajax requests there... is that all your code?

Comment: Nope with my ajax request i just remove my div#projects and add a new one (#demo) with the data result.